# How to reuse existing WebDriver instances in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

My application is a multithreaded program. Each thread will execute a set of test cases. My idea is to create a new WebDriver instance for each thread and close instance when it finishes.

For example: I have 100 test cases which will be executed by 10 threads. Each thread takes ownership of 10 test cases.

As of now for each test case a browser instance is opened. Instead of that, for each thread a browser instance needs to be opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your `WebDriver` instances using a [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). Quoting the JavaDoc on `ThreadLocal`:

> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized copy of the variable. ThreadLocal instances are typically private static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).

Example usage:

```
// for multiple separate test classes you need to share it among your project
public static final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> WEB_DRIVER_THREAD_LOCAL = 
    new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {
        @Override
        protected WebDriver initialValue() {
            // create a new instance for each thread
            return new ChromeDriver();
        }
    };

// get a WebDriver instance in your tests;
// when there is already an instance for the current Thread, it is returned;
// elsewise a new instance is created
WebDriver webDriver = WEB_DRIVER_THREAD_LOCAL.get();
```

Comment: Its working but I am finding it difficult to handle browser memory. It is helpful, if you propose a way to identify the completion of each thread and once individual thread execution is finished, it should close its associated browser instance.
And For Every test case, I need to clear browser memory, in order to make sure not appending current data with old data which resides in browser memory.

Comment: (1) You’ll probably need to hook into your testing framework to determine when all tests are finished and then close the drivers. (2) Not possible in a reliable way. If you require a clean browser for every test, you cannot share instances.